# how to configure liquibase in spring boot app to get generate file with differences between @Entity and database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I want to generate with command mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog or mvn liquibase:dif the changes in my entities but i get empty file.
i want to generate file that allows me to get changes between my database and my entities. any ideas please?
In my application.properties :
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username= username
spring.datasource.password= pswd

spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.cache-duration=3600

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

## Liquibase Configuration

spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.yml
in my pom.xml :

````
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.25.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                <version>4.25.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.25.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    <!--                    <verbose>true</verbose>-->
                        <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.yml</outputChangeLogFile>
    <!--                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.yml</changeLogFile>-->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generateChangeLog</goal>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                                <goal>diff</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>```
my entity : 

    ``` @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Table(name = "test_user")
    public class TestUser {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "username")
        private String userName;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;
    }```
````